# Output the indices of array in descending order

Tags: c

I use the following quicksort function to sort any given array in descending order:

```
int sorting (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(double*)a < *(double*)b );
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n;
    double values[] = { 88.54, 56.65, 100.13, 2.091, 25.223 };
    qsort(values, 5, sizeof(double), sorting);
    for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
        printf("%f ", values[n]);
    }
    return(0);

}
```

Besides outputting the values in descending order, I want to output their corresponding `indices`. For instance, for the given `values[]` array, I would get [2, 0, 1, 4, 3] which indicates the index 2 has the largest values, index 0 has the second largest values, and so on. How can I modify the code above ?

Thank you

Comment: I recommend you read more about [the `qsort` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), especially about what the comparison function is supposed to return.

Comment: As for your problem, you need a second array with the indexes, and you should sort the *index* array. Then, and this is the hard part, you need to figure out a way to pass the value array to the comparison function which uses the indexes to check the values in the value array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It's not hard if you use an array of pointers instead of an array of indexes. Using pointers instead of indexes often simplifies C programming tasks, imho.

Comment: Indices for an array are from 0, increasing by one to the length minus one. Descending order would mean reversing this. Or do you mean the values? That's straight-forward. As a sidenote: Despite it's name, `qsort` is not required to use the quicksort algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine values with indexes in a `struct`, sort them, and print indexes along with values:

```
struct ind_val {
    int index;
    double value;
};
int sorting_ind_val (const void * a, const void * b) {
    double lhs = ((struct ind_val*)a)->value;
    double rhs = ((struct ind_val*)b)->value;
    if (lhs < rhs)
        return 1;
    if (lhs > rhs)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
...
double values[] = { 88.54, 56.65, 100.13, 2.091, 25.223 };
struct ind_val pair[5];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    pair[i].index = i;
    pair[i].value = values[i];
}
qsort(pair, 5, sizeof(struct ind_val), sorting_ind_val);
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    printf("%d: %f\n", pair[i].index, pair[i].value);
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/zKmd6I)

```
2: 100.130000
0: 88.540000
1: 56.650000
4: 25.223000
3: 2.091000
```

Comment: @stark Care to explain what you mean? After all, the function appears to work perfectly fine in the demo (see the link near the bottom).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you so much. This is not in descending order? I try to flip the sign but doesn't work

Comment: @Medoo This is now fixed, along with the demo. Thanks for pointing this out!